# Filter a share point list by another list in power apps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I've organized a list that includes a 'Person' column with details such as 'Employee' and 'EmployeeId'

[image]

Additionally, I have another list that captures 'EmployeeId' and their corresponding technological expertise. This creates a many-to-many relationship between employees and technologies.

[image]

In the context of a Power App, I'm aiming to create a search functionality where users can filter employees based on both their names and technological expertise. Could you guide me on how to effectively implement this search using the information from these two interconnected lists?

This is a preview of the current application

[image]

This is the current filter I use to filter employee by their names. It's working correctly.

```
Filter(
    Skills,
    Or(
        StartsWith(
            Employee.DisplayName,
            SearchInput1.Text
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Maybe you can try this: Filter('Skills', StartsWith(Employee, TextInput1.Text) || 'EmployeeId' in Lookup('Technological List', 'EmployeeId', EmployeeId, 'Technology'))

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working